# How to add 20 pixels of white at the top of an existing image file?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have an image of size `w` by `h`. In Java, I need to create an image that is size `w` by `h+20` where the top `w` by `20 pixels` is white, and the rest of the image is the same as the original image.

Essentially I want to know how I can add 20 pixels of white to the top of an existing buffered image.

So it would be something like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  BufferedImage originalImage = [the original image with a specific file path];
    ...code to create a new image 20 pixels higher...
    ...code to paint originalImage 20 pixels down on the new image
    ...code to save the new image...
}
```

Comment: @Amir, "Essentially I want to know how I can add 20 pixels of white to the top of an existing buffered image."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suggestion:

1. Use [`GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(int width, int height)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage%28int,%20int%29) to create a `BufferedImage` of the same width, but with a height that's +20.
2. Use [`BufferedImage.createGraphics()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29) to obtain the `Graphics2D` object of this image.
3. Use [`Graphics.setColor(Color c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29) and [`Graphics.fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to draw the white top
4. Use [`Graphics.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) to draw the original image to the specified coordinates of the new image.
5. To save the new image, read the [Writing/Saving an Image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) tutorial.

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageManipulationDemo {
    private static BufferedImage ORIGINAL;
    private static BufferedImage ALTERED;
    private static final GraphicsConfiguration config = 
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            loadImages();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();             
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void loadImages() throws IOException {
        ORIGINAL = ImageIO.read(
                ImageManipulationDemo.class.getResource("../resources/whitefro1.jpg"));
        ALTERED = config.createCompatibleImage(
                ORIGINAL.getWidth(), 
                ORIGINAL.getHeight() + 20);
        Graphics2D g2 = ALTERED.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, ALTERED.getWidth(), 20);
        g2.drawImage(ORIGINAL, 0, 20, null);
        g2.dispose();

        // Save image
        ImageIO.write(ALTERED, "PNG", new File("alteredImage.png"));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Manipulation Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ORIGINAL)));
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ALTERED)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes it make sense. For example:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      BufferedImage originalImage = [the original image with a specific file path];
      BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth() + 20 , originalImage.getHeight() + 20 , YOUR_IMAGE_TYPE);
      for (int i = 0 ; i < newImage.getHeight() ; i++){
          for (int j = 0 ; j < newImage.getWidth() ; j++){
               if (j > 20 && i > 20){
                     newImage.setRGB(i,j, originalImage.getRGB(i - 20, j - 20));
               } else{
                     newImage.setRGB(i,j, YOUR_RGB_VAL);
               }
          }
      }
    }
```

P.S.
I hope the code is correct. I didn't test it but only wrote it on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you need to investigate [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and [Graphic2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html). You can retrieve `Graphic2D` from the `BufferedImage` to manipulate and draw on your image.

Basically, you should create a 2nd image with greater dimension and draw the first one in it at the right position to leave white space in the 1st one.