# Create a margins editor component like the one in Microsoft word

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jspinner

I have a Java Swing application that i want to create a nice component in it like a component in Microsoft word. In Microsoft word you can change the margins of your document like in here :
[image]

The trick here is that if you change the Top margins to (Let's say) 1.5" then the Preview image will change to show this, so the lines will move down a bit in the image to show that change in the margins so the user can feel how much his document will be affected by this change. So for example if i change the left margin to (4.0") the image will look like this :

[image]

What i did is create 2 images a blank page image + another image that contains lines only(Lines image), like these 2 images :

[image]
[image]

I inserted each image in a JLabel above each other, and now when i change the JSpinner top margin value, i keep the "blank page" image fixed, but i change the border of the "lines image" to move it down a bit. The trick worked fine for the top margin, but the behavior goes totally wrong if i change the bottom/right/left margins.

Here is my code that i apply when changing any JSpinner value :

```
private void marginSpinnerStateChanged() {
    //1. Get the approximate values of all margins :
        int topMargin = (int)( Float.valueOf( topSpinner.getValue().toString() ) * 8 );
        int bottomMargin = (int)( Float.valueOf( bottomSpinner.getValue().toString() ) * 8 );
        int leftMargin = (int)( Float.valueOf( leftSpinner.getValue().toString() ) * 8 );
        int rightMargin = (int)( Float.valueOf( rightSpinner.getValue().toString() ) * 8 );

    //2. Apply all specified margins to the lines label : 
        linesLabel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder( topMargin, leftMargin, bottomMargin, rightMargin ) );
}
```

**Can you help me continue this to work right ?**

Comment: As long as you don't make a Swing version of Clippy. I'd vote to delete.

Comment: @glowcoder .. Sorry, i do not understand what do you mean by "a Swing version of Clippy" ?

Comment: oh it was just a joke. Clippy was the annoying paper clip that was always "It looks like you're trying to _____". :)

Comment: ehh .. as I understand it, it's not problem of the spinner(s) but about the logic which creates the preview. Please update the subject accordingly

Comment: @kleopatra ... This is late, but i have changed the post title now. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just draw the image on top of the paper and scale the image as you go. So you would override the paintComponent() method of a JComponent to do something like:

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
```

x - would be the left margin
y - would be the top margin
width - would be (maxWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin)
height - would be (maxHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin)

If you don't like scaling the image you can always use a BufferedImage and then use the getSubImage(...) method to get an image the desired size to be painted.

Comment: This seems interesting. I am currently putting each image in a JLabel. Can you give me a code sample for this ?

Comment: There is also a problem applying this. I want to use decimals like changing the top margin to 0.2 inches, but the drawImage(...) uses int values so no change will appear in the image.

Comment: Look at the [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial for the basics. Instead of using the `drawString` method, you would use the `drawImage` method. You second comment is also relevant to original approach because you can only use pixel values to set the location of the label as well. So whatever you do will be an approximation to the nearest pixel. The user won't notice the difference.

Comment: I have used drawImage(...) and it worked just fine ... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, they don't shift the textual image. Instead, they only show half of it. This is simple image manipulation. For a good example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028780/how-to-add-20-pixels-of-white-at-the-top-of-an-existing-image-file/7028977#7028977).

Comment: I think they do shift the text. If they are inserting a white image on the left, then the indentation of the starting paragraph would not appear.