# Cropping an image in Java

Tags: java, image, crop

I'm trying to cut a certain part of image in Java and save it back to disk. Is there a function that cuts the images from X, Y with the specified width and height?

Comment: Have you tried typing "java image crop" in your favourite search engine? Or in the stackoverflow search field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 20 pixels of white at the top of an existing image file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028780/how-to-add-20-pixels-of-white-at-the-top-of-an-existing-image-file)

Comment: Why on earth was this closed as "too broad"? There's even already a clear and concise answer posted!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'd typically

1. Create a new `BufferedImage` (`dst` below) with the desired width and height.
2. Get hold of it's `Graphics` object
3. Load the original .jpeg image (`src` below)
4. Paint the desired part of that, onto the `BufferedImage`
5. Write the buffered image out to file using `ImageIO`.

In code:

```
Image src = ImageIO.read(new File("duke.jpg"));

int x = 10, y = 20, w = 40, h = 50;

BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
dst.getGraphics().drawImage(src, 0, 0, w, h, x, y, x + w, y + h, null);

ImageIO.write(dst, "png", new File("duke_cropped.png"));
```

**Given this .jpg...**

[image]

**...It generates this .png:**

[image]