# Selenium- screenshot of visible part of page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to get Selenium WebDriver to take screenshot only of the visible part of the page for PhantomJS? I've browsed the source and there is no API AFAICT. So is there a trick to do that somehow?

EDIT: Chrome already snaps only visible part, so removed it as part of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc API for [TakesScreenshot](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) a WebDriver extending TakesScreenshot will make a best effort to return the following in order of preference:

- Entire page
- Current window
- Visible portion of the current frame
- The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser

As PhantomJS is a headless browser it probably doesn't have menus/tabs and other similar browser chrome.  So all you can control is the Dimension of the browser window.

```
// Portrait iPhone 6 browser dimensions
Dimension dim = new Dimension(375, 627);
driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
```

Taking a screenshot will most likely capture the entire page.  If you want to restrict your resulting file to the dimensions you requested you could always 
[crop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894275/loading-cropping-saving-an-image-in-java) to your required dimensions (not ideal but PhantomJS is not a ***real*** browser).

```
  private static void capture(String url, WebDriver driver, Dimension dim, String filename) throws IOException{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(dim);
    driver.get(url);
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    int w = dim.getWidth();
    int h = dim.getHeight();
    Image orig = ImageIO.read(scrFile);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bi.getGraphics().drawImage(orig, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File(filename));
  }
```

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because this is a detailed and conclusive answer on the fact that there is no such API. Unfortunately the method suggested in this answer about setting dimensions and then taking screenshot does not work. 

Thanks for the detailed answer. Mark.

Comment: Happy to help.  The above code "worked" for me - at least it accessed an URL using a particular dimensioned "device" and it captured a screenshot (entire page) and then cropped it to the device dimensions.

Comment: I was referring to raw screenshot after setting dimensions. I'm assuming the cropping would work...

Comment: Indeed, the dimensions name is a little misleading.  Where it is useful is that different dimensions can be used to activate different CSS3 media query style rules for testing responsive web sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: This takes the entire page, and not just the visible area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use robot class for this as belows

```
Robot rb=new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Once you have copied the screenshot on clipboard then u can save it to file.