# Button action to change the color of all tabbedpane panel java swing

Tags: java, swing, background-color, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I have 2 tab(A and B) in tabbedpane.
In A, I write only setBackground(Color.RED);

In B, I put a Button. and the codes likes that:

```
A a=new A();

jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```

I want to change the color of A from B's button action. But I failure.
How can i solve this problem??

Thanks in advance...

---

still my problem not solved. I am posting the whole code:: I used 2 package: "ok","ok1". "ok" contains 1 file named save.java and the code is:

```
public class Save extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;A a=new A();B b=new B();



public Save() {
    initComponents();
}

//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {
    panel1=a.initComponents();
    panel2=b.initComponents();
    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Tab 1", null, panel1, "Just Panel");
    jTabbedPane1.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Tab 2", null, panel2, "Button");
            jTabbedPane1.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
```

---

"ok1" contains 2 file: A.java and B.java.....      A.java::::::::

```
             public class A extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/** Creates new form A */
public A() {
    initComponents();

}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
public JPanel initComponents() {

    jPanel11 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(
            jPanel11);
            jPanel11.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
```

---

B.java::::::::

```
             public class B extends javax.swing.JPanel {
A a = new A();

/** Creates new form B */
public  B() {
    initComponents();


}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
public JPanel initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton1.setText("Action");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            a.jPanel11.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you give me a example of SSCCE???

Comment: It's sort-of self-explanatory, but here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028780/how-to-add-20-pixels-of-white-at-the-top-of-an-existing-image-file/7028977#7028977).

Comment: @Rounak : You are doing coding in the wrong way. I am updating my answer, which resembles your code. Do have a look.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [`TabColors`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752166/230513), which starts with matching tab and content colors, the following modified `TabContent` constructor adds a button that causes all panes to use the same color.

```
private TabContent(final int i, Color color) {
    setOpaque(true);
    setBackground(color);
    add(new JLabel("Tab content " + String.valueOf(i)));
    add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Use my color") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pane.getTabCount(); j++) {
                pane.getComponentAt(j).setBackground(
                    pane.getBackgroundAt(i));
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems you are doing it wrong. First of all don't write these lines

```
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
```

instead write :

```
private A a = new A();
private B b = new B(a);
```

Since a and b, themselves are Panels now, as they extending JPanel class.

So add this to your tabbedPane now :

```
jTabbedPane1.addTab("Tab 1", null, a/*This is your Panel1*/, "Just Panel");
jTabbedPane1.addTab("Tab 2", null, b/*This is your Panel2*/, "Button");
```

Simply add a JPanel variable to your B class and change the constructor of your class B as follows :

```
JPanel panel1;

public B(JPanel panel)
{
    pane1 = panel;
    initComponents(); // make this method return void in it's definition, in both the classes.
}
```

Now inside the actionPerformed() method do this :

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            panel1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
    });
```

Here is small program modified from the previous submission, that resembles your case :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPaneExample extends JPanel
{
    private Panel1 panel1;
    private Panel2 panel2;

    public TabbedPaneExample()
    {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        //panel1 = getPanel("Panel Number 1");  
        panel1 = new Panel1("Panel Number 1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", null, panel1, "Just Panel");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        //panel2 = getPanelWithButton("COLOR");
        panel2 = new Panel2("COLOR", panel1);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", null, panel2, "Button");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

        add(tabbedPane);

        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    private static void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new TabbedPaneExample(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    createAndDisplayGUI();
                }
            });
    }
}

class Panel1 extends JPanel
{
    public JLabel label;
    public Panel1(String text)
    {       
        label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        add(label);
    }
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel
{
    public JButton button;
    public JPanel panel1;

    public Panel2(String text, JPanel panel)
    {
            panel1 = panel;
        button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
                {
                    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            });
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        add(button);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you explain what you doing wrong.

Here is the image of the program as it is started :

[image: AT START]

Here is the image of the second tab with button :

[image: TAB WITH BUTTON ON IT]

Here is the image of the first tab as you click on tab2's button to change tab1's background color to blue :

[image: BACKGROUND COLOR OF TAB1 CHANGED]

Hope this might help you in your endeavour.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new instance of `A`, but use the `A` instance which was included in the tabbed pane. You can either to this by searching your tabbed pane for this `A` instance, or pass the `A` instance to `B` when creating `B`

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what to do.

Comment: The `A a = new A()` should not be present in the code of your `B` class. Post an SSCCE and we can point you where you go wrong